# Programmatically create an order of grouped and bundle product in Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, ce-1.8.1.0, bundled-product, grouped-products

I need a code to create order in Magento programmatically.

I used this script for simple product order and it works good.

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php'; 
Mage::app(); 
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
        ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId());
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                ->setWebsiteId(1)
                ->loadByEmail('test@example.com');
        $quote->assignCustomer($customer); 
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(2770);
$buyInfo = array(
        'qty' => 1, 
);
$quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object($buyInfo)); 
$addressData = array(
        'firstname' => 'Test',
        'lastname' => 'Test',
        'street' => 'Sample Street 10',
        'city' => 'Somewhere',
        'postcode' => '123456',
        'telephone' => '123456',
        'country_id' => 'US',
        'region_id' => 12, // id from directory_country_region table
); 
$billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($addressData);
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($addressData);

$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()
                ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping')
                ->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');
$quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'checkmo'));
$quote->collectTotals()->save();
$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
$service->submitAll();
$order = $service->getOrder();
printf("Created order %s\n", $order->getIncrementId());
```

But i also want to create order of grouped product as well as bundle product,
I try with using grouped and bundle product id but it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is sence that every group and bundle product has a simple product and magento add all those simple product individual 
not as full product sku of group or bundle, so we can use every product's sku in order
for example if we have group product with id 2828 & 2827 so we can order that grouped product like below

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php'; 
Mage::app();  
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$skus = array('2828'=>1,'2827'=>3); // 2828&282 are idproducts and 1&3 are Qty
$email = 'test@example.com';

$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId());
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId(1)->loadByEmail($email);
$quote->assignCustomer($customer);
foreach($skus as $key=>$val)
{
    $quote[] = $quote->addProduct(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($key), new Varien_Object(array('qty' => $val,)));
}
$addressData = array(
    'firstname' => 'Test',
    'lastname' => 'Test',
    'street' => 'test Street 10',
    'city' => 'test',
    'postcode' => '123456',
    'telephone' => '123456',
    'country_id' => 'US',
    'region_id' => 12,
    );
$billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($addressData);
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($addressData);

$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()
                    ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping')
                    ->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');
$quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'checkmo'));
$quote->collectTotals()->save();
$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
$service->submitAll();
$order = $service->getOrder(); 
echo  $order->getIncrementId();
```

Comment: This works for grouped product which really just add the simple products to the cart. But bundle products are added as a parent item with child items. The parent can have its own price and sku (fixed or dynamic), there can be shopping cart price rules for it, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::addProduct()`, especially for complex products. Use `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart::addProduct()` which is also used by the add to cart controller action and takes care for configuring the product and quote item. It takes a product id and the "request info" as parameters, where the request info can be simply the qty to buy (for simple products) or data for a **buyRequest** object. This is basically the `$_POST` data from an add to cart action.

So have a look at what form data is sent to Magento when adding a grouped or bundled product to the cart, then you can simulate this request with:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->addProduct($productId, $request);
```

You can read more about the buyRequest in [this reference](http://www.schmengler-se.de/en/2014/09/magento-info_buyrequest-objekt-referenz/).