# Magento 2 collect total quote after remove item

Tags: magento2, quote

I have a module that removes cart items from **Cron job every day**. 
After removing the item, the **quote total quantity and quote subtotal** amount does not update. By using the below function I want to update the quote data but it **does not work**.

```
    public function updateCart($quoteId,$customerId){

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();//instance of object manager


    /**
     * @var $itemModel \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    $itemModel = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface');//Quote item model to load quote item

    /**
     * @var $q \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote
     */
    $q=$objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote');
    $q->loadByCustomer($customerId);

    $q->collectTotals();
    $q->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);

    $itemModel->save($q);
    $q->save();

    $itemModel->get($quoteId);

    $itemModel->save($q);

}
```

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: I am also getting same issue

Comment: @NavinBhudiya in cron table on db i see this error No such entity with cartId = 341
do you know what's happened ?

Comment: That error coming because that cart id is not found in quate table, Cart id is removed from some where that's y error are coming

Comment: @NavinBhudiya and what is difference between quote id and cart id ...i can not see any cart id on db

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107593/magento-quote-vs-cart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after many search and test, i found answer [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/e93c44e66d256836c18e6a5e7e9f24623f05e25b#diff-29e75e5c62fd3f695c374958d6acca66)

i use Magento 2.1.8 and for fixed this bug on
`vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteRepository.php`
change `load` to `loadByIdWithoutStore` .
final method should be like below

```
   public function get($cartId, array $sharedStoreIds = [])
{
    if (!isset($this->quotesById[$cartId])) {
      //  $quote = $this->loadQuote('load', 'cartId', $cartId, $sharedStoreIds);
        $quote = $this->loadQuote('loadByIdWithoutStore', 'cartId', $cartId, $sharedStoreIds);
        $this->getLoadHandler()->load($quote);
        $this->quotesById[$cartId] = $quote;
    }
    return $this->quotesById[$cartId];
}
```

Comment: so now quote total quantity and quote subtotal update properly?

Comment: @NavinBhudiya yeah